# element.className only returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a little interactive gallery in which people could check/select some picures. I used some  to contain the pictures and add some  in there to indicate selected photographs. Then I typed a little JS code to check or uncheck photographs using the className of the .

So my two problems are :

1. The code doesn't run as expected. Can't select any picture when I'm runnin' my navigator.
2. The console only returns "undefinded" as explain in the code below.

Here's some code : [image: https://i.imgur.com/BDVECeX.jpg]

It's kind of my first attempt in JS and I don't really understand what isnt's not working so I hope you'll got an answer or at least some little indications for me. :)

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Please don't post images of the code. You should paste the real working snippet or at least the text of the code

Comment: try `document.getElementByClassName('the-class')[0]`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I realized it was not the best way to share my question :)

I'll keep it in mind when I'll have another question to ask. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in previous answers the getElementsByClassName method returns a HTMLCollection of elements that have the class name that you pass to the method.  If you need to access any of the items, you will need to do it like an array.

For example, getting the first element of the collection.

```
unselectedClass[0].className;
```

Otherwise you could use a for loop to access each element in the collection.

```
for (var i = 0; i < unselectedClass.length; i++) {
    var class = unselectedClass[i].className;
}
```

Comment: Just the perfect answer !
I didn't find it when I made my research but thank you for having some patience to answer me :)

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` yields a collection of elements. The `className` property is available on a specific element in that list. Not on the list itself.

Comment: ... so the solution is?

Comment: @Jeremy: ... to access the property at the specific element. Not on the list itself.

Comment: @Jeremy: I disagree. Pointing out the source of the error *is* answering the question. I'll leave it to OP to decide how to handle the fact that he's treating a collection as though it was a single element. Someone in comments mentions accessing `[0]`, one answer suggests iterating the collection. I don't have sufficient knowledge of the intended software to recommend either way. The person writing the code needs to understand that they're dealing with a collection, and not a single node, and make an informed decision based on that. Not just copy whatever code appears to solve the problem.

Comment: I'd rather agree with David because it seems more helpful for the newbie I am to get some advices without getting the complete solution. It "forces" me to make some researches and it's cool too. But thank you both, guys !

Comment: As you want. In general, on Stackoverflow, a hint should be posted as a comment. Answers should be real answers, full solutions. But nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection` and `HTMLCollection`. You should check the `className` of its elements.

You can loop through it then get `className` of each element

```
for(let i = 0;i<unslectedClass.length;i++){
   console.log(unselectedClass[i].className);
}
```

Or convert the `HTMLCollection` to a real array using Spread Operator and use `forEach()`

```
[...unselectedClass].forEach(x => console.log(x.className))
```